# SQL Server : update column with value from same table based on choice of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have a table that contains inventory items, where the same item can be stored in multiple places (i.e. Total qty=3, 1 stored in cabinet, and 2 in the fridge, and 0 in the pantry). Each of these have an entry type of "20".

There is also rows with entry type of "10" that control the totals. So, in my program I see "Available" as Entry Type "10", and can view each locations quantities by viewing the Entry Type "20".

After running some updates, I noticed that it took my "10" types to zero even if there were items in the "20" rows (on a certain set of items, which I have a list of to include within an "IN" statement to change only those rows)

I am looking to update that table with some sort of CASE statement (I think) to force "10" entry to be equal to the SUM of the "20" entries.

Table looks like this:

```
ITEM_ID    ENTRYTYPE    QTY       LOCATION_ID
------------------------------------------------
  A01        10          0       ALL-AVAILABLE   <--THIS ROW SHOULD SHOW QTY=3
  A01        20          1          CABINET
  A01        20          2          FRIDGE
  A01        20          0          PANTRY
  A02        10          0       ALL-AVAILABLE   <--THIS ROW SHOULD SHOW QTY=6
  A02        20          2          CABINET
  A02        20          2          FRIDGE
  A02        20          2          PANTRY
```

I think the code is basically something like:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET qty = SUM(t2.qty)
FROM Inventory t2
WHERE (ENTRYTYPE = 10 AND qty = 0) 
  AND ITEM_ID IN (list already generated to be pasted later);
```

Of course, I couldn't make this work for whatever reason. All help appreciated!

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a correlated update.

```
UPDATE t2
SET qty = (select SUM(qty) from Inventory where item_id=t2.item_id and ENTRYTYPE = 20)
FROM Inventory t2
where ENTRYTYPE=10 AND qty=0
```

To restrict the item_id's that get updated, use a `where` condition.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the 1st "from." Getting RED underlines

Comment: Changed this one around a little to remove NULL sums, and placed a COALESCE determination before the SUM. Final was this:

UPDATE t2
SET qty = (select COALESCE(SUM(qty),0) from Inventory where item_id=t2.item_id and ENTRYTYPE = 20)
FROM Inventory t2
where ENTRYTYPE=10 AND qty=0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `ENTRYTYPE = 10` is always the record you want to have the total quantity updated in:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET qty = (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM Inventory WHERE ENTRYTYPE = 20)
WHERE ENTRYTYPE = 10 AND qty = 0;
```

Comment: Down and dirty...I like it.  @TrayS, you will want to try this and other solutions presented to see what works best for your workload.

Comment: this will update the qty to sum of all quantities *for all items* with entry type = 20, which is wrong.

Comment: @vkp - "I am looking to update that table with some sort of CASE statement (I think) to force "10" entry to be equal to the SUM of the "20" entries."

Comment: yes..and that is for a specific item_id.the question only shows one item_id.

Comment: @vkp - I took it that was handled based on this statement: "on a certain set of items, which I have a list of to include within an "IN" statement to change only those rows"

Comment: how will the subquery know that it has to filter for those items, if there is no correlation with the main query? try it yourself on some test data and check.

Comment: @vkp - it doesn't know - my understanding is that OP is providing that piece in their code. It is handled separately.

Comment: @vkp - I've provided an answer based on my interpretation of the question. If you feel that is not correct and interpret it differently, you are free to provide an answer yourself of course.

Comment: @Nicarus..that is what i did before you answered.

Comment: @vkp - I suppose I am not following you then. I've answered based on my interpretation and you disagree. OK. What now? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select i.*, sum(qty) over (partition by item_id) as sumqty
      from inventory i
     )
update toupdate
    set qty = sumqty
    where entrytype = 20;
```